# How to freeze the value of a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

In the search part of my project I've got a [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx), whose values come from the database. For example:

- A
- B
- C
- D
- E
- F

And I have an [`SqlDataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource(v=vs.110).aspx) to bind the query with a `GridView`.

My problem is that whenever I choose a value from the `DropDownList`, it *automatically* selects the first value for example **A**. The code below is in the search button:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = 
      "SELECT Name,Subject,Summery "+
      "FROM Books "+
      "WHERE Subject= N'" + subList.SelectedItem.Value + "' "+
      "AND Name= N'" + searchName.Text + "'";
GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID;
GridView1.DataBind();

if (GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString() == "0")
   lable1.Text = ("Couldn't find it.");
else
   lable1.Text = "";
```

Comment: Is this code in the button clicked event handler?

Comment: looks like you're rebinding the data to the grid every time that's why your not getting the correct item selected

Comment: @eric_s I didn't use the wizard for the select part. so what should I do to fix it? I should be able to search when the button is clicked!

Comment: Just to clarify, your dropdown list is refreshing (selected item set back to A) when you click the button to refresh the grid. Is the grid populating with the correct data? (i.e. select B from the dropdown, click button, get B's data in the GridView.)

Comment: @eric_s when the page is load the gridview is empty, so its not refreshing the gridview. but when i choose the first item from the droplist and fill the text box with the correct name that exist it bring the data, but only with the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that's populating your dropdownlist (which you've not posted so we've no idea what you're doing there). I'm guessing this needs to go into 'Page_Load' and be wrapped in `if (!IsPostBack)`

It should look something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadMyDropDown();
    }
}


private void LoadMyDropDown()
{
    //Code to load dropdownlist
}
```

The issue you've got is that every time the page is being refreshed/updated the data is being rebound to the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after you bind the dropdown menu.

```
dropDownMenu.SelectedIndex =-1;
```

Comment: in the button handler[btnSearch_Click].